Python matplotlib program hangs after every interval after using for loop
Below is my python matplotlib code. It was working fine until I used the for loop in it to reduce the repeated code lines. Now, after every 1 second, the bar chart window hangs for 1 second. When I try to mouse hover on the bar chart it hangs for every 1 second. Also, when I try to drag the entire window on screen then also, it hangs for every 1 second.
import os
from importlib import reload

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

import cred


def run_script():
    """
    This function runs the script.
    """
    # Set the background color of the entire window
    plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = "#131722"
    plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 8), sharex=True)

    # Set background color
    fig.patch.set_facecolor("#131722")
    for ax in axs:
        ax.set_facecolor("#131722")

    def animatechart(i):
        reload(cred)
        fold = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data")
        bnifty_csv = os.path.join(fold, f"{cred.symbol0.split(":")[1]}.csv")
        pe_csv = os.path.join(fold, f"{cred.symbol1.split(":")[1]}.csv")
        ce_csv = os.path.join(fold, f"{cred.symbol2.split(":")[1]}.csv")

        chart_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")
        chart = os.path.join(chart_path, "chart2.png")
        while True:
            try:
                bankniftydata = pd.read_csv(bnifty_csv, skip_blank_lines=True)
                pedata = pd.read_csv(pe_csv, skip_blank_lines=True)
                cedata = pd.read_csv(ce_csv, skip_blank_lines=True)
            except Exception as e:
                e = "Exception Occured!"
                print(e)
                continue
            break
        option_data = pd.merge(pedata, cedata, on="Time", how="inner")
        data = pd.merge(bankniftydata, option_data, on="Time", how="inner")

        symbols = [cred.symbol0, cred.symbol1, cred.symbol2]
        for symbol, ax in zip(symbols, axs):
            ax.clear()
            ax.bar(
                data["Time"],
                data[f"{symbol.split(":")[1]}Volume"],
                color="#9598a1",
            )
            ax.axis("off")
            ax.autoscale(tight=True)
            ax.set_title(
                f"{symbol.split(":")[1]}   {cred.resolution}   {cred.from_date()}   {cred.to_date()}",
                loc="left",
                color="#9598a1",
                fontsize=12,
            )

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig(chart, facecolor="#131722", bbox_inches="tight")

    ani = FuncAnimation(
        plt.gcf(),
        animatechart,
        interval=1000,
        cache_frame_data=False,
    )
    plt.show()


run_script()

For now, I didn't find any solution yet to try.
If I don't use for loop then the program does not hang after every interval. But I want to use for loop to optimize the code which leads to hanging.
Additional Information:
CPU: Intel Core i5 14th Gen
Memory: 32 GB
